# "unexpected EOF while parsing"

Tags: python, simpsons-rule

I'm trying to implement this part of code.
The error "unexpected EOF while parsing" occurs in the last line. I tried various things but can't seem to find what is wrong (T^T)

```
def simpsonsumme(f, a, b, N):
    X = np.linspace(a, b, N)
    if N%2 == 0:
        return ((b-a)/(3*(N)) * ( f(0) + 4*np.sum(f(X[1:-1:2])) + 2*np.sum(f(X[2:-2:2])) + f(N)))
```

(I'm trying to implement the simpsons rule. f is a function; [a,b] the intervall of the integration and N the number of sections in [a,b], maybe that is somewhat helpful context)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because you're missing your final right parentheses.

Comment: Oh, I just failed to copy+paste that into the question. Thanks for letting me know xD

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux (or a mix, e.g. with WSL)? Try running your file through `dos2unix` or `unix2dos`: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/dos2unix.htm

Comment: This code doesn't do anything by itself. What do you do to get the error?